# Drag elements UIImageView. Using a NSMutableArray

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, ios5

**.m**

```
self.elements=[myElements getElements];

imagesElements = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
for(ElemetsList *item in self.elements)
{
        UIImageView *oneelement = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:item.imgElement]];
        oneelement.frame = CGRectMake(item.positionX, item.positionY, item.width, item.height);
        oneelement.userInteractionEnabled=YES;
        [imagesElements addObject:oneelement];
}

for(UIImageView *img in imagesElements) 
    [self.view addSubview:img];
```

Then I try to interact with the elements:

```
-(void)touchesMoved:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
    UITouch *touch = [[event allTouches] anyObject];

    for(UIImageView *img in imagesElements) 
    {  
        if([self view] == img)
        {
            CGPoint location = [touch locationInView:self.view];
            img.center=location;
        }
    }
}
```

But "if ([self view] == img)" is always "NO". Therefore, the elements do not drag.
How to drag and drop items if they are in the array?

Comment: what would be the main purpose of this line?

`for(UIImageView *img in imagesElements) [self.view addSubview:img];`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you add your image views, you make them **subviews** of `self.view`, therefore you need to test whether `img` is in the `subviews` array.  It can't be equal to the view that contains it.

Comment: Thank you for your reply! But how to correctly do this? If I scan an item in uberayu touchmoved the elements are moved